# Angular 4 + Karma testing a component

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a component that inject its parent component as:

```js
constructor( @Host() app: ParentComponent) {
  ...
}
```

When I run the test, I get the following message:

**Error: no provider for ParentComponent**

I have already included all the dependencies used in both, parent and child components.  Do I need to do anything specific to inject the host component?

Here is my complete test:

```js
describe('ChildComponent: Component', () => {
 //declare the component
 let comp: ChildComponent;
 let ca: ComponentFixture<ChildComponent>;

 //setup
 //first the async call to compile all the external templates
 beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   imports: [
    ...
   ],
   declarations: [
    ParentComponent,
    ChildComponent
   ],
   providers: [
    ...
   ]
  })
  .compileComponents(); 
 }));
 //then the sync call to create the instance
 beforeEach(() => {
  
  ca = TestBed.createComponent(ChildComponent);
  comp = ca.componentInstance;

  ca.detectChanges();
 });

 afterEach(() => {
  comp = null;
  ca = null; 
 });

 //define the tests 
 it('should have items...', () => {
  let count: number = comp.someArray.length;
  expect(count).toBeGreaterThan(0);  
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a provider for this component.

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   imports: [
    ...
   ],
   declarations: [
    ParentComponent,
    ChildComponent
   ],
   providers: [
     {provide: ParentComponent, useClass: ParentComponent}
   ]
  })
  .compileComponents();
```

Comment: Thanks, this trick helped me. Can someone explain why I needed to do this though? :) As I didn't have to provide the component anywhere else than this spec-testfile.